# Does this implies $(X, \tau_X) $ discrete space?

Tags: general-topology, continuity

$(X, \tau_X) $ and $(Y, \tau_Y) $ be two topological space such that

1. $card(\tau_Y)\ge 3$
2. $f\in C(X, Y) \quad , \forall f \in Y^X$.

Does this implies $(X, \tau_X) $ discrete space?

I know if the domain is a discrete space or the codomain is an indiscrete space the every map is continuous.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By hypothesis 1., there's a nonempty open set $V$ in $Y$ for which $Y\setminus V$ is nonempty.
Fix a $v\in V$ and a $w\in Y\setminus V$.

For any subset $U\subseteq X$, consider $f:X\to Y$ with $f(x)=v$ if $x\in U$ and $f(x)=w$ otherwise.
By hypothesis 2., $f$ is continuous, so $U=f^{-1}(V)$ is open.